# Запись значения по адресу pymem

Tags: python

Мне нужно записать значение типа double по адресу "0EEAD0E0" программы, но я никак не могу найти как это сделать с помощью модуля pymem для python. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что означает фраза "Мне нужно изменить значение типа double у адресса "0EEAD0E0" программы". Что значит изменить значение типа double? Что за адрес? Какой программы?

Comment: @dIm0n тип данных изменять не нужно, я хочу изменить значение адресса, я уточнил что адресс типа double по скольку думаю что это на что то влияет. в адрессе хранится значение баффа в игре

Comment: По моему, под виндой на С++ можно решить эту задачу с помощью следующих АПИ - ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory. А как это делают в питончике?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pymem

addr = 0x0EEAD0E0
value = 1.0

pm = pymem.Pymem("program.exe")
pm.write_double(pm.process_base + addr, value)
```